# Django RadioButton as a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, radio-button, foreign-keys, modelform

Good day!

I keep options for my radio button in MySQL database. I want these options appear on my radio buttons in a form. Some times I want to open and edit my form and entries. So when I open an existing entry I would like to see correct radio button checked. How can I do it?

I have the following models:

```
class SomeType(models.Model):
    type_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(SomeType)

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = SomeModel
       fields = ['name', 'type']
```

Here is a view sample:

```
def some_view(request, _id):
    entry = SomeModel.objects.values().get(id=_id)
    form = SomeForm(entry)
    return render_to_response("/myapp/some.html", {'sometypes': SomeType.objects.all(), 'form': form})
```

And finally a part of my form template:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.name == 'sometype' %}
    {% for sometype in sometypes %}
      {% if forloop.counter == field.value %}
        <input type="radio" name="sometype" id="id_sometype_{{ sometype.id }}" value="{{ sometype.id }}" checked="">
      {% else %}
        <input type="radio" name="sometype" id="sometype_{{ sometype.id }}" value="{{ sometype.id }}">
      {% endif %}
      {{ sometype.type_title }}
    {% endfor %}    
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What is wrong here? 
How can I render a form with checked in the same radio as in my database for this entry (_id)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the widget in form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('name', 'type')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['type'].widget = forms.RadioSelect
```

and let the Django to render the form as usually:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

If you want to render the radio input manually, you will have to do something like this (`is_radio` filter is my custom filter):

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field|is_radio %}
        <p{% if field.field.required %} class="required"{% endif %}>{{ field.label }}:</p>
        {% for choice in field.field.choices %}
            <div class="radio">
                <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="control-label">
                    <input type="radio" name="{{ field.name }}" id="{{ field.auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.0 }}"{% if field.value == choice.0 %} checked{% endif %}> {{ choice.1 }}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-danger">
                {% for err in field.errors %}<li>{{ err }}</li>{% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        ...
```

But I don't recomment to use `RadioSelect` for foreign key, the listing can be quite long. If you have only a few choices and you modify the data rarely, I would recommend to remove `SomeType` model and use `type = models.CharField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)` instead.